# mina setup/deploy help needed

Tags: deployment, mina

I´m new to mina and only have a hosting package with an ssh access but with no root privileges.
My prob is that I get an "Permission denied, please try again" if I run mina setup.
By extending the `deploy.rb` wit the following line:

```
set :term_mode, :nil
```

I can run mina deploy but I received this error:

```
-----> Using git branch 'master'
$ git clone "development/www.mydomain.com/scm" . --recursive --branch "master"
fatal: destination path '.' already exists and is not an empty directory.
! ERROR: Deploy failed.
```

I know that the www.mydomain.com isn´t an empty folder cause mina creates with the setup the "shared" and "releases" folders.
So I don´t know what I have to do to make the deploy happend.
Any hint?

Answer (score 1):

You need to check settings in your deploy.rb file.  Looks like mina is attempting to clone into your user home directory.  Also the repository path looks incorrect.  It should be using a full path for both the repository path and the target path.

For example you should see something like:

`-----> Cloning the Git repository
$ git clone "http://github.com/username/project.git" "/home/username/deploy_path/scm" --bare
Cloning into bare repository '/home/username/deploy_path/scm'...`

Answer (score 0):

This error is most likely caused by not having a deploy block in your deploy task. Your deploy task should look like this:

```
task :deploy => :environment do
  deploy do
    invoke :'git:clone'
    # Other deploy tasks ...

    to :launch do
      # Run some commands when launching the appplication
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Soluction deploy mina

```
set :repository, 'git@bitbucket.org:my_user/my_repo.git'
set :branch, 'master'
```